# Trying to copy rendered/rich text HTML code into clipboard (node.js environment)

Tags: javascript, node.js

My HTML looks like this:

```
<p><strong>bold text</strong><i>italic text</i></p>
```

I wanted to copy that HTML to my clipboard. But I'm working in a node.js environment. In other words, I'm executing that code by typing `node script.js` in my terminal.

Searching online, I stumbled upon this note package: https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy.
It enables you to access your clipboard from a node.js environment like this:

```
const clipboardy = require('clipboardy')
clipboardy.writeSync('<p><strong>bold text</strong><i>italic text</i></p>')
```

However, what I want is to copy the rendered/rich text HTML to the clipboard. In other words, this:

> **bold text** *italic text*

Searching online again, I found this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3/.

It uses the following function to achieve what I want:

```
function copyToClip(str) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

However, I can't use `document` in my node.js environment. So I'm stuck.

How can I solve this problem? Or maybe it's impossible to achieve this in a node.js environment?

Comment: When you select some text from an app and then copy it, the clipboard stores the data in multiple formats, depending on what the source app can offer. Then the app you're pasting the content, picks up the most suitable format. "Rich text" doesn't exist, it is created by the app you paste the data from the clipboard.

Comment: @Teemu In theory the Rich text do exists. If you copy some rendered text from Browser or through Javascript `clipboardData.setData` API, you would see multiple entries inside Windows Clipboard. One is plain text `CF_TEXT` type and another `CF_HTML` type.

Comment: @ttimasdf Yes, that's what I'm saying in my comment above: "_the clipboard stores the data in multiple formats_".